# How to evaluate the performance of a model in production when labeling data is costly?

Tags: machine-learning, performance, metric

I have come to a problem for which I can't find a solution.

Let's talk about a hypothetical binary classification problem in which you have some years of (human) labeled data. The final objective is to remove the need for a human to label the data. You train the model with, for example, the first 3 years of data, and then evaluate the model with the last year or last two years. A different but valid approach that tries to mimic a real-life situation is testing every month with all the data available up to that month.

Let's assume that the choice of the train and evaluation methods explained above are not relevant. You get everything done and deploy the model in production, now the human that had to label manually 1000 samples a day is not needed but on the other hand, you stop receiving the "ground truth" thus preventing you from evaluating the model in production!!

Instead, you could reduce the work hours of the human and label just some % of the data, and here arises my question. Which % would be representative enough to assert with confidence that the model is performing well/poorly in production? How do you even calculate what "representative" means? I suppose that it is dependent of the variability of the data, but how do you measure it? I did a lot of googling but haven't found any relevant information I would love to hear how do you measure a model performance in production when "creating" new ground truth is costly

Comment: This sounds like a power calculation. Are you familiar with that concept?

Comment: I am not. Any resource to start?

Comment: JBStatistics has some good videos: https://m.youtube.com/results?search_query=Jbstatistics+power+ Once you’re familiar enough with those ideas, we can discuss how this would apply to your problem.